# "for" iterates only once when i want to read from local storage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I want to read everything from local storage with button click and display it in my array but "for" loop iterates only once

Sending something to local storage:

```
onClick1() {
    var value = document.getElementById('textfield').value; 
    localStorage.setItem("todoData" + Date.now(),value);
```

Getting it back:

```
onClick4(){
  for (var j = 0; j < localStorage.length; j++){
    this.todos = [localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(j))];
    }
```

Expected results:
I want to see everything that is in local storage

actual results:
I only get one element

Comment: for (const key in localStorage){
  this.todos.push(localStorage.getItem(key))}

Comment: _"I only get one elemen"_ - Because you're overwriting whatever is in `this.todos` on every round of the loop

Comment: Thank You @Andreas!!! You showed me the way!

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

Replace this line:

`localStorage.setItem("todoData" + Date.now(),value);`

with this line:

`localStorage.setItem("todoData" + Date.now(), JSON.stringify(value));`

and this whole function:

```
onClick4() {
  for (var j = 0; j < localStorage.length; j++) {
     this.todos = [localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(j))];
  }
}
```

with this function:

```
onClick4() {
 let tempArray = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
     tempArray.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))));
 }
 this.todos = tempArray;
}
```

Comment: Why should TO call `JSON.stringify()` on a string? o.O

Comment: @Andreas It is always a good practice. Better se safe than be sorry. Example: storing "0" into localStorage makes it a string, and comparing it strictly (===) (using strict comparison is considered a good practice too and is also highly recommended by webpack and CRA) anywhere might give undesired results. Stringify and parse makes us programmer's lives a little bit easier.

Comment: Yes, but... Calling `JSON.stringify()` on a string is unnecessary - and `.value` will always return a string.